# Resize images with batch file recursive directories

Tags: batch-file, resize, image-resizing, mogrify

I'm trying to resize a bunch of images on a Windows machine, with imagemagick installed and also have git for windows.

The images need to be resized to 50% of their current size.

Inside a root directory theres directories that could contain images and others directories with images. I need to resize all the images. In my particular case I have a total of 250 folders (nested in different levels) with a total of 4110 images.

**Example root folder**

```
RootFolder
   Folder A
      ImageA.png
      SubFolder A
          ImageB.png
          ImageC.png
   Folder B
      Subfolder B
          ImageC.png
```

I'm trying this way, but if fails to get the correct paths.

```
for /r /d %%a in (*) 
do 
    find . -name "*.png" -print0 | xargs -0 mogrify -resize 50%
```

Error message

```
find . -name "\Default\*.png" -print0   | xargs -0 mogrify -resize 50
Access denied - .
File not found - -NAME
File not found - -PRINT0
```

Comment: the code you've posted is a mix between bash and batch. You have installed unix subsistems for windows/cygwin/something else?Also imagemagick?

Comment: It looks like those three lines of code should all be on one line, but you also need to look at the `find` command and reference `%%a` somewhere too!

Comment: sorry... I forgot to mention, I have imagemagick installed and also have git for windows. I will edit my post fr a more accurate response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this command line in a batch file to resize all PNG images in current directory and all subdirectories except hidden directories and files to 50% in width and height and overwrite input file using **IrfanView**?

```
@for /R %%I in (*.png) do @"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\IrfanView\i_view32.exe" "%%I" /resize=(50p,50p) /convert="%%I"
```

The same command line for execution directly from within a command prompt window without usage of a batch file:

```
for /R %I in (*.png) do @"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\IrfanView\i_view32.exe" "%I" /resize=(50p,50p) /convert="%I"
```

Open a command prompt window, run `for /?` and read the output help.

For the options of **IrfanView** (freeware for private usage) read the text file `i_options.txt` in program files folder of installed **IrfanView**.

I don't have **ImageMagick** installed and you have not posted the **ImageMagick** command line to resize a PNG image which is the reason why I posted a command line solution using **IrfanView**.

One more note: There is no need for a batch file for this task. Open **IrfanView**, click in menu **File** on menu item **Batch Conversion/Rename** and use this dialog to select with a few clicks all *.png image files in your directory tree, set the options for resize and PNG optimization and execute batch conversion.

Comment: Thank you. I manage to to do export using InfarView and your command line instruction. Also tested using the app.